# Создать кнопку с атрибутом onclick

Tags: javascript, dom

Подскажите, как через JS DOM создать подобный `input`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="remove_market_meta('MarkeID9')" value="Remove">
```

Важен атрибут `onclick` с функцией.

Грубо говоря к этому как-то нужно добавить `onclick` с функцией в которой будет лежать нужный `id` для передачи в функцию удаления.

```
input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.value = "Remove";
fragment.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.value = "Remove";
input.setAttribute("onclick", "remove_market_meta('MarkeID9')");
fragment.appendChild(input);
```

А лучше сделать так:

```
input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.value = "Remove";
input.onclick = remove_market_meta('MarkeID9');
fragment.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: пробовал оба варианта, второй не работал корректно, ибо сам `id` генерировался и в итоге при создании следующей, обе кнопки работали по последнему.
А вот первый вариант подходит, просто допустил ошибку не поместив функцию в кавычки.